# Prove that the radius of $(ABC)$ is smaller than the radius of $Max[(ADC),(ABD),(CBD)]$.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

> Given $3$ points $A,B,C$ and a third point $D$ lying outside the circumcircle $(ABC)$. Say $ABCD$ is a convex quadrilateral. Prove that $(BDC)$ is larger than $(ABC)$.

Moreover, here is another problem.

> Given $3$ points $A,B,C$ and a third point $D$ lying insider the circumcircle $(ABC)$ such that $ABDC$ is a convex quadrilateral. Prove that $(DBC)$ is larger than $(ABC)$.

[image]

Comment: It’s very easy by the extended law of sines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Apply the extended law of sines on $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle BCD$ with side $BC$ in both triangles. Then note that if $D$ is inside $(ABC)$, $\angle D+\angle A>180$ and it’s converse.

Comment: thankyou, I got it.